# applying a patch before going to main service

Tags: svn, patch

Say we have 3 layers of adding files to a repository.

1. Main - receives patch and if approved the patch is applied
2. Group Leader, receives patch from group and forwards the patch to main
3. Devs - create patches that are forwarded to Group Leader

Right now Group Leader forwards the patches one by one, is there a way for Group Leader to apply the patches and submit them all at once?

Keep in mind that Group Leader also makes changes to the repo so changes of its own can be added to the batch or fix other patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Group Leader just has to use `svn diff` and specify the minimum and maximum revisions of the patches applied one by one. It will create a big patch containing all the one by one patches.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. so Group Leader doesn't use svn patch but rather svn diff? Could you share a sample?

Comment: See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html for examples (at the bottom). This will create the patch you can then apply on Main.